# PHP Codeigniter - Joining a posts table to a TOXI tag database storage system

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, tags

My function within my model is as follows:

```
    function get_all_posts($where='')
{
    $this->load->database();
    $this->db->select('blog.title,blog.permalink,blog.content,blog.author,blog.date,COUNT(comments.ID) as commentcount');
    $this->db->from('blog');

    if($where!=''){
    $this->db->where($where);
    }

    $this->db->order_by("blog.ID", "desc");
    $this->db->join('comments', 'blog.ID = comments.postID','left');
    $this->db->group_by('blog.ID');
    $query=$this->db->get();

    $data=$query->result_array();

    return $data;


}
```

I have two further tables -

post_tags : tagID postID
tags: tagID name

I have been playing around with joins to try and get it such that along with all my posts etc, the variable returned contains any and all tags that apply to the aforementioned post are passed..

I have tried everything with little to no success.

Could someone please advise?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using $where correctly.

In this case, $where should be an array of this form:

```
$where = array(
    "field_name" => "match_value",
    ....more conditions.......
);
```

So make sure that $where is an array and not a string.